# Echo date strtotime from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have this chunk of code written using PHP

```
<?php
$dateTime = "$review->published_at";
$dateTimeSplit = explode(" ",$dateTime);
$date = $dateTimeSplit[0];
echo date('d M Y',strtotime($date));
?>
```

I am trying to write the above with JS and this is what I have so far

```
var dateTime = review.published_at;
var dateTimeSplit = dateTime.split(" ");
var date = dateTimeSplit[0];
```

It's not complete, since I have no idea how to write this line with JS

```
echo date('d M Y',strtotime($date));
```

Any help?

Edit:
Right now the date is '2017-11-10'. I need it to be '11 Nov 2017'.

Comment: Try using [**momentjs**](http://momentjs.com/docs/) library, it is very popular for working with dates in javascript

Comment: Mhh... You already have that line echoed, and you can't echo with JS. What exactly do you need?

Comment: Do you want send date to a js variable?

Comment: Right now the date is '2017-11-10'. I need it to be '11 Nov 2017'. @Teemu

Comment: please update sample result of you code.

Comment: Where does `review.published_at` get its value? From the `echo`? Can't you create the value originally correctly?

Comment: As you can see from the PHP codes, it's an array. I got the value from the database. @Teemu

Comment: ?? How is that? `echo date('d M Y',  ...)` "returns" a string which is exactly what you need ..? What is "_the date_" in your question?

Comment: Seams like I misunderstood what you meant. What I want is to RECREATE the PHP codes using JS.

Comment: In that case, I've misunderstood your question ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way of doing it

```
var dateTime = review.published_at;
var dateTimeSplit = dateTime.split(" ");
var date = dateTimeSplit[0];

var d = new Date(date); // set as new date
var months = [      // Initialize months
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];
// get desired format
var formatted_date = d.getDate() + ' ' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear();
alert(formatted_date); // check result
```